# Why does the c# compiler still read compile code from unused methods?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Say I have two methods, one calls the other.  The second method has code that will generate a compile time error.  Since it's not called, why does the compiler still bother to process it?

```
void method1()
{
    var i = 1;
    //method2();
}

void method2()
{
    int i = "2";
}
```

Comment: The compiler can't guarantee that it will never be called. And besides, you really don't want to leave mistakes like this only for them to come back and bite you hard later.

Comment: It can't guarentee that it won't ever be called, however it knows (I'm assuming this) that it's not being called right now. So I guess I'm curious why the compiler doesn't skip it until there are known calls to the method. The quality of the code or practice aside, strictly from a compiler's pov.

Comment: The compiler can't assume that it's not being called "right now".

Comment: Because of what I said - reflection, runtime type info discovery etc - you are strongly typed when compiling, but you can do whatever you want at runtime. Reflection can be used to discover methods and properties of types and invoke them - if you include some code in a type, the CLR maintains this method or property info in the manifest so that reflection can be used. You have no guarantee what happens at runtime!

Comment: can you edit your answer to include what you wrote in your comment Charleh?

Comment: Tweaked my answer to include some more info

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't be sure that someone else won't call that method at runtime using reflection. Your code MUST compile or it's not valid code - if it's never used... comment it out!

To expand on this:

Basically at compile time you are strongly typed - .NET will type check everything to ensure that what you are trying to do is legal, however, you can still throw exceptions at run time due to null references, bad casts etc etc.

Reflection is a component of the .NET framework that allows a developer to inspect the properties/fields/methods etc of an assemblies types via the assembly metadata

Reflection allows runtime type discovery and inspection of these types, it also allows invocation of methods/properties and modification of fields etc. (You can even create new generic types at runtime or completely new types altogether).

In other words, you can't guarantee that code you **think** won't be called, isn't called somewhere else at some point. For reflection to be possible, every bit of code needs to be valid and compilable

Whether that code will succeed at runtime is another story - but that's why we have exception handling.

Comment: Don't comment it out! that leaves horrible legacy code. Delete it!

Comment: I suppose that depends if you are in the middle of fixing it and need to fix it at a later date..! But what developer really has time for that :D

Answer (score 1):

And then what if somebody else uses your compiled code later on and decides to use it?

Even with private methods Reflection can complicate matters.

If you don't use it, lose it. (or at least comment it out)

Comment: I'm not concerned in this example of what may or may not happen in the future with another programmer.  Unless this type of "forewarning" is why the compiler is bothering to deal with uncalled methods.

Comment: Just because you are not concerned, doesn't mean the compiler should let it through unchecked. How is the compiler supposed to know what you are intending to do at a later date. Also, why leave stub code that doesn't compile in the first place? The correct behaviour is to throw new NotImplementedException.