# Can't run Program.cs in VSCode if there is an error in another non-used .cs file

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've written a lot of Python (and a bit of C/C++ many years ago) but am now staring on C# (.NET).

I'm using VSCode as my IDE.

I have the following folder structure

```
test/
├─ Program.cs
├─ Car.cs
```

with

```cs
//Program.cs

class Progam
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Hello SO!");
    }

}
```

and that runs fine when I press `CTRL+F5` (Run without debugging).

I've then moved into classes in C#, which is the `Car.cs` file.

I have an error (I forgot a semicolon)

```cs
//Car.cs

class Car
{
    string color = "red";
    int n_wheels = 4 // Wups, missing semicolon
}
```

Note, I haven't changed the `Program.cs` file, but now when I press `CTRL+F5` I get the error

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\C#\test\Car.cs(8,21): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\Users\Me\Documents\C#\test\Test.csproj]`

I might still quite have understood how .NET/C# compiles the stuff and runs the program, but I just wonder, why it throws an error in the `Car.cs` when that class isn't used at all in the `Program.cs`, which is the only file that contains a `Main` function.

I could understand if I've imported the `Car` file but I do not - I don't use it anywhere and it does not have a `Main` function.

So my question is; how do I avoid such stuff, when I have files that I'm currently developing (but am not using) that might have some bugs/issues due to it being under construction?

Comment: It requires all code to compile.  It doesn't mean it will run all code (until you call it).  How to avoid it?  Add the semicolon :)

Comment: Thats just the way it works.  Why would you want to run code that wont compile? Also Car.cs is part of the same component... I would argue if you have a component that is not referenced then maybe there is a way.... But it would have to be in a different component.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro that is exactly my point; I don't use the `Car.cs` file at all i.e why does it bother if it complies or not, since it is not used.

Comment: If it worked the way you're proposing one might then wonder "Why didn't it notify me of the missing semicolon in `Car.cs` before now?" when `Car` does finally get used. Further, what if you _are_ using `Car` but via reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MyNamespace.Car")`)?  Consider the depth of analysis the compiler would have to do to determine if a type is truly being used or not, and it still wouldn't be 100% accurate. It's much easier to just have the compiler...compile all code fed to it.  If you don't want the compiler to check a file, then take steps to prevent its compilation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the c# compiler still read compile code from unused methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652109/why-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-still-read-compile-code-from-unused-methods) or [Will the compiler only compile code that can get executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10192076/150605) or [C# Compiler optimization - Unused methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5204667/150605) or [Why can't dead code detection be fully solved by a compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33266420/150605)

Comment: I can think of many reasons... But one reason is that in C# just because you don't reference a class or type it does not mean you are not going to use it.  In C# is perfectly valid to instantiate a type during runtime using reflection... you can even load entire components(libraries) dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments, and after viewing the OP's bio I can see where this question is coming from.

You are comparing python's execution path to C#'s.

In **python** (yes, I know python is compiled - I'm simplifying):
The interpreter is going over the commands in a sequential manner and executing them.

i.e. If you have an `import` within a function - the interpreter will not know or care about the import until it is required, and thus code with bad syntax in another module (= file, for C# speakers) will not affect your program.

**C#** works a bit differently. The first step is compiling the code and creating a binary file which will be executed.
That file is the binary representation of **all the source code files referenced in your project**.
Hence:

1. Any file that has syntax error will fail the project compilation
2. The binary will not build.
3. You will not be able to execute the binary.

This is why a syntax error in **any** file will not allow you to execute your code.

Another way to think about is is that in **python** the imports are done in run time, while in **C#** its in compile time.
In both cases a malformed reference file will break the process.
C# simply does it earlier.

> So my question is; how do I avoid such stuff

Well, you can fix the syntax error, or comment that part out until you get to it...